# Addition characters in xml rss output

Tags: android, xml-parsing, cdata

i have a app that receive data from xml & parse them into app.
but in output there are addition characters (xml tags)
[image]
What should I do?

```
 public final String getElementValue2( Node elem ) {  
 Node child;  
 if( elem != null){  
     if (elem.hasChildNodes()){  
         for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() )
         {  
             if(child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)
             { 
                 CDATASection cdata = (CDATASection)child;
                 cda =cdata.getData().toString();
             }  
         }  
     }  
 }  
 return "";
```

> XML Web Address http://news.tebiran24.com/feed/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the XML sends an additional link with your data. Just remove the unneeded data from the response and you will have your intended answer.

Code for that would be:

```
// I am guessing `cda` is the response you got from the feed which contains the additional characters.

String[] data = cda.split("a>");
cda=data[1];
```

Now print cda. There won't be any extra characters.

Comment: i do it but return this error : The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

Comment: Oh I am sorry..see the updated answer.. *data* must be String Array..See updated answer

Comment: You need to escape the forward slash.. See updated answer.. Checked this one in an Online compiler..Sorry for the recurring mistakes